# javascript and loadUrl error

Tags: javascript, android, webview

i know that to run a javascript function in webview we need to load it in loadUrl(). In my program everything works fine javascript gets called when i use it in loadUrl, but instead of running javascript on the same page, loadUrl("javascript:function()") vanishes my previous page and run this javascript "function()" in a totally new blank page..

for eg. i tried to fill a form automatically using command:

> view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('password').value = 'my_passoword'");

what happens is, the page which consists of ID-'password' vanishes and a new blank page generates consisting of 'my_password' only

where is the problem?

Comment: Try creating a function that sets the value of the input field and call that. Maybe Android does not like to evaluate the function in load url.

Comment: problem is it's not my site...  I'm trying to make some kind of auto login system in my app using my college's website.. i cannot create my own function or change the website coding...

Comment: Why not? You can retrive the contents of the website, save jt to string, inject your JavaScript and load it in the webview

Comment: i think your way would work too, but it would be slow, as i have to login and navigate through two more pages and retrieve data.. as soon as possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android WebView always returns null for javascript getElementById on loadUrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602117/android-webview-always-returns-null-for-javascript-getelementbyid-on-loadurl)

Answer (score 2):

> [Using loadUrl to run javascript loads different page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065188/using-loadurl-to-run-javascript-loads-different-page?rq=1)

anonymous self-invoking function works fine.. i.e.

```
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('password').value = 'sb14november';})()");
```

and as a loop around i think  Bojan Kseneman answer will work too..

thanks to all!! :)

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: This library is only for evaluating JavaScript and it created a new WebView instead of using an existing one :/

You can also try [js evaluator library](https://github.com/evgenyneu/js-evaluator-for-android)

```
jsEvaluator.evaluate("put your JavaScript code", new JsCallback() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(final String result) {
    // you get the result here (optional)
  }
});
```

Comment: what is the API support for this library

Comment: Supports Android version 3.0 (Honeycomb) and newer.

Comment: @SubrotoBiswas Sorry, this library is no good. It creates a new WebView instead of using an existing one :/